# Unable to prove palindrome number for "11" in C programming

Tags: c, return, return-value, reverse, palindrome

leet code palindrome problem, i am trying to prove test case " 11 "  is a palindrome but i am unable to , despite other test cases passsing correctly

```
bool isPalindrome(int x){
    if(x<0)
        return false;
        
    if(x >= 0 && x < 10)
        return true;
        
    long unsigned int rev;
    long int rem = 0;
    long int y = x;
    while(y>0)
    {
        rem = y % 10;
        rev = rev*10 + rem;
        y /= 10;
    }
    
    if(x == rev) 
    {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

For input `11` the output is false, but true was expected.

tried printing the reversed number in different IDE, the reversed number was 11 but still it is returning false ?

Comment: Please post your code as formatted text, [not as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557).

Comment: You don't initialize rev in the first place, so it will contain random data. You can print rev to see what it contains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code that need to be fixed:

The variable rev is not declared before using it. You should declare rev and initialize it to 0 before the while loop.
In the while loop, you are modifying the value of y, which should be the reversed number. Instead, you should be modifying the value of x.
The comparison if (x == y) should be if (x == rev) to check if the original number is equal to the reversed number.
Here's the corrected version of the code:

```
#include <stdbool.h>

bool isPalindrome(int x) {
    if (x < 0)
        return false;
    if (x >= 0 && x < 10)
        return true;
    
    long int rev = 0;
    long int y = x;

    while (y > 0) {
        long int rem = y % 10;
        rev = rev * 10 + rem;
        y /= 10;
    }
    
    if (x == rev) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now, the function should correctly check if a given integer is a palindrome. For example, isPalindrome(11) will return true.

Answer (score 3):

As noted in comments, you do not initialize `rev` before using it in `rev = rev*10 + rem;`.

If your other test cases pass, this is purely by chance, as the uninitialized `rev` has an indeterminate value. You are likely counting on it being `0` and that is one *possibility*. If you are counting on this, then explicitly initialize it as such.

Note also that the following is overly verbose.

> ```
>     if(x == rev) 
>     {
>         return true;
>     }
>     else {
>         return false;
>     }
> ```

When you could simply write:

```
    return x == rev;
```

As an alternative approach, you might convert the input int to a string, then check that that string is a palindrome.

```
bool stringIsPalindrome(char *s) {
    const size_t len = strlen(s);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < len / 2; i++)
        if (s[i] != s[len - 1 - i]) 
            return false;
    
    return true;
}

bool isPalindrome(int x) {
    char y[50] = "";
    sprintf(y, "%d", x);

    return stringIsPalindrome(y);
}
```

Comment: A lot of the function is overly verbose. The shortcut branches at the top are not required either: https://godbolt.org/z/csGrcMzG6

Comment: The if/else that just returns true/false stood out as a particularly common one that shows up a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```
rev = rev*10 + rem; // rev was never initialized.
```

Automatic (local) variables in C have indeterminate values, we need to explicitly initialize `rev` to 0 before using it like so:

```
long unsigned int rev = 0;
```

Here's an alternative approach where we convert the number to a string, and then check if it is a palindrome:

```
#define BUFSIZE 128

bool isPalindrome (int x) 
{
    char buf[BUFSIZE];
    const int len = snprint (buf, BUFSIZE, "%d", x);
    
    if (len == 0 || len == 1) {
       return true;
    } else {
       char *start = buf;
       char *end = buf + len - 1;

       while (start < end) {
            if (*start++ != *end--) {
                return false;
            }
       }

       return true;
}
```